# Kibana 4 as Azure website is not connecting to ElasticSearch service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, kibana-4

I am working on a task to deploy ElasticSearch as an azure cloud service with 3 Master + Data Nodes and Kibana 4 as an Azure Website. The ES (2.3.1) service is active and I get the green health status on Chrome sense on retreiving health of ES cluster.
I have used the Kibana 4 binaries in https://github.com/iremmats/kibana4-azure-website for creating a json application that can be deployed as Azure website. The json application that I have created along with configuration for server.js, kibana.yml runs successfully on local VS using node.exe and I am able to discover my ES instance indices on it. However, the moment I deploy this nodejs application to Azure Website and attempt to browse Kibana 4 on Azure website I get Kibana: Bad Gateway exception. Looking into the network timeline of azure website hit, it throws HTTP 502 error on attempting to connect with ElasticSearch cloud service instance.
Below is network timeline screen shot.The IP address mentioned is the IP address of ES cloud service.
[Kibana Bad Gateway error and network timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J8RQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was caused by Azure virtual network configuration for your ElasticSearch cloud service.

I think you may try to do two ways below for the configuration.

1. Adding a new endpoint for the cloud services to allow the inbound access for port 9200 at the endpoint setting on Azure portal.
2. Following the article [How to manage NSGs using the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/) to configure the access rules for subnets in your virtual network between the website and cloud services.

However, I think it's not necessary for integrating the independency Kibana instance with the ElasticSearch instances. In fact, Azure has supplied the `Elasticsearch and Kibana` integration environment in the Azure Marketplace that you can directly create without any additional configuration. Please try to access the url https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/Elasticsearch%20and%20Kibana/resetMenuId/ to see it, or search the words "Elasticsearch and Kibana" in the search bar of Azure Marketplace to find it.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.